# Import dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

I'd like to import a module dynamically and only if it's required.

To archive this, I created a little mixin:

```js
import {extend} from "vee-validate";
import {email, required} from "vee-validate/dist/rules";

export const rules = {

    methods: {
        addRule (name) {
            switch (name) {
                case 'required' :
                    extend ('required', {
                        ...required,
                        message: 'This field is required'
                    });
                    break;
                case 'email' :
                    extend ('email', {
                        ...email,
                        message: 'This field is required'
                    });
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
};
```

Now my question: I would like to import `email` and `required` only if they are required. So if I add only the `required` rule, there's no need for the `email` rule to be imported. How can I import these only if they are required?

Answer (score 0):

You should use import function. Note that it returns `promise`, so your `addRule` method must be `async`.

```
const { required } = await import('vee-validate/dist/rules.js')
```

edit:
This approach will not prevent loading of full `rules.js`.
So, another advice is to split rules into separate files.

**required-rule.js**

```
export { required } from 'vee-validate/dist/rules.js'
```

**mixin**

```
const { required } = await import('required-rule.js')
```